# Laravel index.php routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I've tried everything I could find but nothing works. There is something with my Xampp or routing.
This Works:

```
/public/index.php/admin/website/overview
```

Does not work:

```
/public/admin/website/overview
```

Message:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

So I went to the config of Xampp and removed the # in this line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And I also changed:

> AllowOverride None

To:

> AllowOverride All

But it's not working. So I hope someone can help me with this. If I use php artisan serve it also works fine without index.php but I want to fix this.

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the config? #beentheredonethat

Comment: in your apache conf, are you point the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory` to the project/public ?

Comment: @kenken9999 When I try that it doesn't work at all, not with index.php but also not without index.php

Comment: if you point the path to .....project, it is incorrect , https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#configuration

Comment: because any peoples can see `http://your-site/.env` included your databse login namd and password

Comment: I point it to projectname/public. By default it is: C:/xampp/htdocs/

Comment: I have pointed it to: C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/public.

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess file for apache configuration follow [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls)

Comment: Really weird if this is it, since Laravel ships that exact config with the installation since 5.1 IIRC.

Comment: Try restarting your Apache server.